# Excel VBA value storage/conversion issue

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple table:[image]

The total % are using the following formula:

> =SUMIF($Z$23:$AL$23;"%";Z24:AL24)

Where I am basically summing a value, if it's column header is '%'. Then I have a VBA procedure which simply loops through these % Totals and checks whether they are equal to 1 or not such as following:

```
If Cells(iRowLoop, 39).Value <> 1 Then ' show user an error message and stop procedure
```

The problem is, that the very first 100% cell (with value of 18 245) claims, that it's value is not equal to 1.
I tried the following things:

- Multiply the value by 10 000 000, but there is nothing else in there, just simple '1'
- Store value as double to see, if by any chance the value is not like '100.00000001' but it returned the value of '1' again.

I have also checked whether the green percentages contain whole numbers (they are manual user input) and they do, so there is no way how the result could be anything else but plain 100%...but excel still tells me (the VBA procedure) that the first number is not 100%.

How to solve this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell actually **displays** "100%" then:

```
Sub OneHundredPercent()
    If ActiveCell.Text = "100%" Then
        MsgBox "100%"
    End If
End Sub
```

will avoid any roundoff or conversion problems:

[image]

Comment: so simple, didn't think of that! Even though it does not fix the whole problem, but it could be some sort of excel bug. thanks!

Comment: @RobertJ.  **Not an Excel bug.**  It's just that Excel is VERY fussy about floating point values........the alternative would be to apply some kind of **rounding** to avoid values that are very close to 100%, but not exactly 100%.